# Is Cache memory located in the CPU or at the motherboard?

Tags: memory, cpu-cache

I have a doubt whether cache memory is located in the processor or at the motherboard?

Comment: Sounds like school assignment.

Comment: Sounds like plain lazy

Comment: @Olli @Shark Sounds like you guys are whiners...

Comment: And for the record, there has been a time the cache memory was located on the motherboard, so I understand there can be some confusion. (Check this page from 2001: http://www.pcguide.com/ref/mbsys/cache/structMotherboard-c.html)

Comment: This question is redundant.  All CPUs have some amount of cache, and motherboards themselves usually do as well (although it is not a requirement, it depends on the specific architecture).  This is like asking "do cars run on gas or diesel?".  Voting to close.

Answer (score 7):

Most computers have a multi-layer cache approach.  The first layer - L1 cache is always located on the processor.  L2 cache, the next layer up, can either be located on the CPU or on the motherboard depending on the architecture.  Some systems also have a third layer of cache L3 which again could be located on either the CPU or the motherboard.

Older 486 systems, for example, had L1 in the CPU and an optional L2 on the motherboard.

Most modern systems have all the cache on the CPU.

Comment: Around that time all cache on the motherboard was also common. E.g. the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DEC_Multia I owned shipped with no cache and an option to add L1 cache on the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though cache is primarily located on the CPU nowadays, but in the past computer architecture was different, which meant cache was located on the Motherboard and CPU as opposed to the Motherboard. I'm currently learning about computer architecture and learning where it was located was confusing at first.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1154751)

Answer (score -1):

Kind of obvious, but anyway.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache):

> A CPU cache is a cache used by the central processing unit of a computer to reduce the average time to access memory. The cache is a smaller, faster memory which stores copies of the data from the most frequently used main memory locations.

Thus, the cache is always attached to the CPU itself and has nothing to do with the motherboard or even the memory.

Edit: Some people feel the need to downvote without giving comments, so I might want to add that this holds for **modern** systems as cache could be used on motherboards too, but isn't nowadays.

Comment: All that quote (and really the first line of the wiki article) states is that the cache is used by the CPU, no mention of where it is stored. You can store L1 cache on the motherboard with a high throughput bus to it and it would still be "cache used by the central processing unit"

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete Please read my post again in which I explicitly said that cache could be used on motherboards, too.

Comment: I see where you state " the cache is always attached to the CPU itself and has nothing to do with the motherboard or even the memory." but that does not clearly define where the cache is at. An attached HDD does not physically sit on a MB or anywhere else yet it is attached.